# org.w3c.dom.Document prints an invalid XML files

Tags: java, xml, jsoup

I have an XML `org.w3c.dom.Document`, coming from an HTML `org.jsoup.nodes.Document`.

When I serialize the `org.w3c.dom.Document`, it produces an invalid XML file: it does not close the `META` tag.

Why? Is this a bug? from `jsoup`? from java `org.w3c.dom`? from the `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`?

Related bugs:

- `W3CDom.fromJsoup fails when xmlns is defined`  https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/1096
- Should `org.jsoup.nodes.Document.toString()` produce a valid XML file?  https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/1097

Example code:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.W3CDom;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Test130e {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String html = "<html><head><script async src=\"http://example.com/script.js\"></script></head></html>";

        org.jsoup.nodes.Document jsoupDoc = Jsoup.parse(html); 
        System.out.println("+++ jsoupDoc.toString()");
        System.out.println(jsoupDoc.toString());


        Document w3cDoc = new W3CDom().fromJsoup(jsoupDoc);
        String xml = w3cDocToString(w3cDoc);

        System.out.println("+++ xml");
        System.out.println(xml);

        // this previous xml file is invalid, and so it fails to parse it
        // The element type "META" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</META>".
        Document w3cDoc2 = parseXml(xml);
    }

    static Document parseXml(String content) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        return documentBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    }

private static String w3cDocToString(Document w3cDoc) throws TransformerException {
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(w3cDoc);
    transformer.transform(source, result);
    return result.getWriter().toString();
}

}
```

Output:

```
+++ jsoupDoc.toString()
<html>
 <head>
  <script async src="http://example.com/script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body></body>
</html>

+++ xml
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script async="" src="http://example.com/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>

[Fatal Error] :5:3: The element type "META" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</META>".
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 3; The element type "META" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</META>".
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
    at playground.Test130e.parseXml(Test130.java:116)
    at playground.Test130e.main(Test130.java:110)
```

Why does `w3cDocToString` build an invalid XML file (it does not close the `META` tag)?

Is this a bug? from `jsoup`? from java `org.w3c.dom`?

---

**Update**

About the comment of @Alohci:

> Have you tried adding `transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");` to your transformer configuration?

Interesting!
If I add this, then the output of the transformer discards the META tag (it is not there). Why?

Also, if I add the following line before that, it says that it is already "xml". It is so strange!

```
System.out.println(transformer.getOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD));
```

---

Why does `w3cDocToString` build an invalid XML file (it does not close the `META` tag)?

Is this a bug? from `jsoup`? from java `org.w3c.dom`?

Comment: I ran this on my local and I got the same thing. If I modify the XML created by jsoup by terminating the <META> tag, the javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder#parse does not puke up blood. I'm going to concur that this looks like a bug in jsoup because it does not create a <META> tag with the appropriate ending tag. Here's your chance to make a contribution to the open source community perhaps.

Comment: I just went to jsoup to file a bug report and discovered that you'd beaten me to the punch. Good job :)

Comment: Have you tried adding `transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");` to your transformer configuration?

Comment: @EricGreen, I already contribute to the open source community. here it is my last pull request on jsoup :) https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/pull/1071

Comment: @Alohci, Interesting! If I add this, then the output of the transformer discards the META tag (it is not there). Why? Also, if I ask for the OutputKeys.METHOD before that, it says that it is already "xml". It is so strange! I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Kudos to you @DavidPortabella!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug in `org.w3c.dom`, since that's not rendering the XML.

The DOM implementation neither forgets nor remembers to close tags, since it's just an in-memory representation of the structure (the *OM* in DOM stands for *Object Model*). The model can be turned into XML, JSON, ProtocolBuffers, etc., which all have different encodings. Whatever renders it as XML is what's "forgetting" to close the tag.

You are using an implementation of the `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` abstract class to convert the DOM into XML, but the concrete class is unknown/unspecified. It seems as though that's what's generating the faulty XML.  You might want to print out `transformer.getClass()` to see what the actual implementation is: it's dependent on environment settings, service providers in the classpath, etc.

Caveat: I've never heard of jsoup before.

Comment: `org.jsoup.helper.W3CDom` constructs a `org.w3c.dom.Document`, using a w3c `DocumentBuilder`, and its `createElement` node functions; You cannot "forget" to close a tag; this is done by the `org.w3c.dom`. So, it looks to me a bug in `org.w3c.dom`, as weird as it might sound, or in the `Transformer`.

Comment: again, `org.jsoup.helper.W3CDom` is using `org.w3c.dom.Document` to create elements. if the transformer does not close a tag (and thus, making an invalid xml file), then there is a bug there (not in jsoup), in my opinion. I also updated the question with some more info at the bottom, showing a very weird behaviour from the `Transformer`. Note: The `Transfomer` (which renders the XML) is not from jsoup, but from `javax.xml.transform`.

Comment: @DavidPortabella good point about `javax.xml.transform` - I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

(Clarified my answer in response to comment; the comment is no longer relevant to the answer in its current form).

In HTML a `<meta>` element is self-closing; there is no end tag.

You have constructed a DOM Document, which is a tree of nodes, in which the topmost node is an HTML element.

You have then serialized the DOM Document using the JAXP serializer without specifying an output method. The default output method depends on the root element, which is HTML, so you are getting HTML serialization. The HTML serializer adds an unclosed META tag to the output.

Comment: I am transforming Jsoup Document to a w3c Document, which is XML. In XML, the META tag should be closed. Read the question again, please.

Answer (score 0):

HTML != XML
Valid XML, but invalid HTML:

```
<script src="jacoco-resources/sort.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

Valid HTML:

```
<script src="jacoco-resources/sort.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So:

```
        Document template = ....

        //So, we need to generate the HTML format! 
        Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();

        // for "XHTML" serialization, use the output method "xml"
        // and set publicId as shown
        t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");

        t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_PUBLIC,
                            "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN");

        t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM,
                       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd");

        // For "HTML" serialization, use
        t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
        java.io.Writer writer = new java.io.FileWriter(path + "/code-coverage-total.html");
        // Serialize DOM tree
        t.transform(new DOMSource(template), new StreamResult(writer));
```